# Sull'uso del verbo "riformare"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Ho trovato nei dizionari che il verbo "riformare" può avere il significato di "rinnovare" o "trasformare allo scopo di migliorare, dando forma diversa e migliore". Ho dei dubbi però sull'uso di questo verbo in tale senso. In [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/riformare) ho trovato questa frase a modo di esempio:

> Il parlamento ha deciso di *riformare* la legge sul lavoro.

Si potrebbe anche scrivere, per esempio, questa frase?

> Recentemente *ho riformato* la cucina del mio appartamento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Come le altre risposte già indicano, "riformare" è un termine molto tecnico che si usa solamente per le leggi. Anche usarlo per un regolamento privato suona strano (ad esempio, non direi mai *Nell'ultima assemblea dei soci, abbiamo riformato il regolamento del tennis club*).

Per la frase sulla cucina:

- "ristrutturare", o anche informalmente "rifare la cucina", dà più l'idea di un grosso cambiamento che richiede dei muratori (abbattere un muro, ripiastrellare il pavimento);
- "rinnovare", o "rimettere a nuovo" si usa anche per modifiche minori (ad es. cambiare gli elettrodomestici, spostare tutti i mobili).

Comment: C'è anche un altro significato moderno di "riformare": esonerare qualcuno dal servizio militare per insufficienza fisica. Naturalmente dopo l'abolizione della leva obbligatoria è caduto in disuso.

Answer (score 4):

> Recentemente ho *riformato* la cucina del mio appartamento.

L'uso di 'riformare' in questa frase è improprio; occorre usare 'rinnovare'.

Si usa 'riformare' quando si deve modificare uno status che ha una valenza giuridica derivante da atti o provvedimenti di natura pubblicistica.

Comment: ...o “ristrutturare” (detto della cucina).

Comment: "ristrutturare", o anche informalmente "rifare", mi dà più l'idea di qualcosa che richiede dei muratori; "rinnovare", o "rimettere a nuovo" si usa anche per cambiamenti minori (es. cambiare o dei mobili).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Giusto: entrambi rientrano nella definizione "trasformare allo scopo di migliorare, dando forma diversa e migliore" su cui si interroga Charo.

Answer (score 3):

"Riformare" nel senso di "rinnovare" è un termine che si applica solo a leggi: *riformare [la legge sul] lavoro*, *[le leggi sulla] sanità*, *[le leggi sulla] scuola*. Infatti, in questi contesti si può sostituire con il sinonimo *rinnovare*.

Tuttavia, il contrario non è possibile. "Rinnovare" è una parola più generica: *rinnovare un locale*, *rinnovare la grafica*. Non si può dire *riformare un locale*, perché "riformare" ha un uso più ristretto, e in genere non si può sostituire "rinnovare" con "riformare" all'interno di una frase.